# Spring: Handle child collection update the right way

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Let's say that I manage an online shop. I want to be able to add and update products via a REST API.

The expected DTO would be something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "iPhone 11 Pro",
  "price": 999,
  "pictures": [
    {
      "url": "http://image.com/image1.jpg",
      "description": "image 1"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://image.com/image2.jpg",
      "description": "image 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using JPA, this would require the 2 following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private Integer price;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
  private List<ProductPicture> pictures;
}

@Entity
public class ProductPicture {
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Product product;

  private String url;

  private String description;
}
```

How to handle a product update? In all tutorials / sample codes I find, it's always a very basic example with a single entity having no collection.

I think about some options:

- retrieve the product from DB, empty the "pictures" list and refill it, then save;
- retrieve the product from DB, iterate over all pictures to find matches then remove/add what is needed, then save;
- maybe that there is a Spring/Hibernate magic for handling this?

I don't like the 2 first ones.

I'm almost thinking to opt for a NoSQL database since it would be a lot easier for this use case... even if it's probably not a good reason.

Also, I'm not in favor of using a dedicated endpoint for this (like POST or DELETE on `/products/1/pictures`).

Could you please share a sample code to handle the update using Spring / Hibernate?
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look at Spring Data Rest.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using the @Embeddable and @ElementCollection annotations that I didn't know, which looks to be a perfect fit for what I wanted to do.

```
@Entity
public class Product {
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private Integer price;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<ProductPicture> pictures;
}

@Embeddable
public class ProductPicture {
  private String url;

  private String description;
}
```

This way the update is super-easy:

```
Product dbProduct = productRepository.findById(product.getId()).get();
// ...
dbProduct.setPictures(product.getPictures());
productRepository.save(dbProduct);
```